# Formatting NSPredicate for Photokit Fetch

Tags: ios8, photokit

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to formulate filers for photokit queries, specifically, how to formulate an NSPredicate when you only want to retrieve certain mediaTypes. In my case, I'm trying to retrieve all albums (i.e. PHCollectionAssets), though I only want the photos in those albums. I'm confused as to how to formulate my NSPredicate to do this. I found the code below in the docs that filters certain mediaSubtypes, but I just want to filter by the PHAssetMediaTypeImage mediaType. Would someone be able to explain the syntax of the NSPredicate code below and how I could set up a predicate along the lines of `@"mediaType == %@, PHAssetMediaTypeImage"`, that doesn't cause my PHFetchRequest to crash, as it does now?

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
fetchOptions.predicate = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"(mediaSubtype & %d) != 0 || (mediaSubtype & %d) != 0", 
        PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama, PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:fetchOptions];
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that there is a subtle difference : `PHAssetMediaSubtype` is a bit mask value, while `PHAssetMediaType` is just an int. It doesn't really change their nature but maybe the predicate interpreter simply refuses to apply the bitwise AND operator `&` to `PHAssetMediaType`. For that one you need to use the regular equality operator `==`.

So, if `fetchAssetsWithMediaType` is not good enough for you because you want only assets in a given collection and there is no `fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:withMediaType:` method, you can do that :

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
fetchOptions.predicate = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResult = 
    [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:anAssetCollection options:fetchOptions];
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you give is from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHFetchOptions_Class/index.html).  It's filtering the `PHAssets` by their `mediaSubtype`, which is of type `PHAssetMediaSubtype`, an enum.  You use the logical AND operator to test whether the asset's `mediaSubtype` is of one or more of the possible subtypes.  The example tests whether the PHAssets to be returned from the fetch are either panorama photos (`PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama`) or high frame rate videos (`PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate`).

If you want to fetch only images, you need to do that. Fetch images. Don't fetch all assets and filter by `mediaSubtype`, as it is unnecessary.

Try the method:

```
 + (PHFetchResult *)fetchAssetsWithMediaType:(PHAssetMediaType)mediaType options:(PHFetchOptions *)options;
```

like so:

```
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];
```

This will return all images.  Optionally, pass `PHFetchOptions` to further filter the *images* returned by this fetch.

Comment: Thanks. I would still like to group and present the returned images as "albums" in a tableview. Would I still be able to do this if I request all images?

Comment: You could use [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum... to get the albums, then fetch the assets using [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:...] with the asset collection as a parameter.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetCollection_Class/index.html